# UPSERT function on a REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, upsert

I have written an apex class for inserting records into salesforce.Is it possible for me to implement the 'Upsert' functionality through a REST API in salesforce?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you encountering errors? You should make an attempt before asking here. At face value the answer seems to be yes.

Comment: You mean upsert a record using REST API outside of Salesforce ?

Comment: what is your external system language ?

Answer (score 1):

- The main difference between Insert and Upsert is, you need an External ID beyond ID in Salesforce object
- Assuming that External Field is X, your request would look like:

> curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/MyObject__c/X__c/999999 -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @updates.json -X PATCH

Where @updates.json contains other data pieces of your object

```
  { "field1" : "d1", .... ,"fieldn","dn"}
```

*Note:*

- I am assuming you know how to get Bearer Token and translate this curl call to appropriate external language level HTTP request.
- **Ref:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm